# Rails 5 API + Vue.js frontend: form to invite users with devise_invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, devise-invitable, devise-token-auth

I am writing an invitation form with Vue.js. The invites should POST to a Rails 5 API. I am using `devise_invitable` for the invitation logic and email dispatch. However, I am having a problem with intercepting the `create` method, as I will be sending the invitation to multiple users so I want to perform a `User.invite!` for each user in the params.

My **invite.vue** file, which contains the form to post:

```
<template>
  <b-row>
    <b-col>
      Invite {{form.length}} members

      <b-form @submit.prevent="submitStaffInvite" id='staffInvite'>
        <div v-for="(row, idx) in form">
          <b-row>
            <b-col cols="3">
              <b-form-group id="firstNameGroup" label="First name">
                <b-form-input id="firstNameInput" name="user[first_name][]" type="text" v-model="row.firstName" autofocus></b-form-input>
              </b-form-group>
            </b-col>
            <b-col cols="3">
              <b-form-group id="lastNameGroup" label="Last name">
                <b-form-input id="lastNameInput" name="user[last_name][]" type="text" v-model="row.lastName"></b-form-input>
              </b-form-group>
            </b-col>
            <b-col cols="3">
              <b-form-group id="emailGroup" label="Staff email">
                <b-form-input id="emailInput" name="user[email][]" type="text" v-model="row.email"></b-form-input>
              </b-form-group>
            </b-col>
            <b-col cols="3">
              <b-button @click='removeRow(idx)'>Remove invitation</b-button>
            </b-col>
          </b-row>
        </div>
        <br />
        <b-button-group>
          <b-button @click.prevent='addRow'>Add invitation</b-button>
        </b-button-group>
        <br />
        <b-button-group>
          <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Submit</b-button>
        </b-button-group>

      </b-form>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => {
      return {
        form: [
          {
            email: '',
            firstName: '',
            lastName: ''
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      addRow: function () {
        this.form.push({
          email: '',
          firstName: '',
          lastName: ''
        })
      },
      removeRow: function (idx) {
        this.form.splice(idx, 1)
      },
      submitStaffInvite: function () {
        this.$axios.post('http://localhost:3001/auth/invitation', this.form)
          .then((res) => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
              this.$notify({
                text: res.data.message,
                group: 'alerts',
                type: 'success'
              })
            }
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            error.response.data.errors.forEach((err) => {
              this.$notify({
                text: err,
                group: 'alerts',
                type: 'warning'
              })
            })
          })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

my **users/invitations_controller.rb**

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters

  def create
    # TODO
    # Send email to each user in the form.
  end

  def edit
    sign_out send("current_#{resource_name}") if send("#{resource_name}_signed_in?")
    set_minimum_password_length
    resource.invitation_token = params[:invitation_token]
    redirect_to "http://localhost:3001/auth/invitation/accept?invitation_token=#{params[:invitation_token]}"
  end

  def update
    super do |resource|
      if resource.errors.empty?
        render json: { status: "Invitation Accepted!" }, status: 200
      else
        render json: resource.errors, status: 401
      end
    end
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:accept_invitation, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
  end
end
```

my **routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Using devise_token_auth for the API
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth',
                                      defaults: { format: :json },
                                      controllers: {
                                        invitations: 'users/invitations'
                                      }
  ...
end
```

I can see that the following routes exist:

```
PUT      /auth/invitation(.:format)            devise/invitations#update
POST     /auth/invitation(.:format)            devise/invitations#create
```

The problem I can see here though is that I'd expect the routes to look like this:

```
PUT      /auth/invitation(.:format)            users/invitations#update
POST     /auth/invitation(.:format)            users/invitations#create
```

This behavior might be caused by the `devise_token_auth` gem, which I'm not sure how to correct.

Again, when I submit this form I'd expect to be able to intercept the `create` method, so to then call `User.invite!` on all the users that are listed in the form. I've tried adding a `byebug` or `binding.pry` inside the `create` method but the code doesn't appear to execute, which means it's being bypassed.

The error message I see is:

```
Processing by Devise::InvitationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"_json"=>[{"email"=>"asd@ad.com", "firstName"=>"Test", "lastName"=>"Last"}], "invitation"=>{"_json"=>[{"email"=>"asd@ad.com", "firstName"=>"Test", "lastName"=>"Last"}]}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):
```

Am I not supposed to pass the form data to the `devise_invitable`'s create method? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your routes to

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', skip: [:invitations]

devise_for :users, path: "auth", only: [:invitations],
controllers: { invitations: 'users/invitations' }
```

For more information you can refer to [this article](http://gabrielhilal.com/2015/11/07/integrating-devise_invitable-into-devise_token_auth/)